# How to open Protractor/Jasmine Test inclusion/exclusion window in Webstorm

Tags: jasmine, protractor, webstorm

How to open the Window Titled as "Select the Test or Suite to Include / Exclude" in Webstorm for Protractor/Jasmine Tests?

I've seen it in [this Video](http://youtu.be/VLMyI7QKcwg?t=1m45s) at 1:45, but did not find any documentation how to open it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available through a [`ddescriber for jasmine`](http://andresdominguez.github.io/ddescriber/) plugin:

> This is an idea plugin to quickly run jasmine unit tests and suites by
>   switching between `describe()` / `ddescribe()` / `xdescribe()` and `it()` /
>   `iit()` / `xit()`.
>
> Just type Ctrl + Shift + D (Command + Shift + D on a
>   Mac) to launch a dialog that lets you choose which suites or unit
>   tests you want to include or exclude.

[image]

Comment: I'm glad that people are using the ddescriber. http://andresdominguez.github.io/ddescriber/